How to rotate a periodic structure in LAMMPS?
I want to rotate a periodic structure like this one

by a 10 degrees around a z-axis (perpendicular to the plane) that goes through the center of the simulation box.
After writing this in LAMMPS,
variable xc equal "lx/2."
variable yc equal "ly/2."
variable zc equal "lz/2."

displace_atoms all rotate ${xc} ${yc} ${zc} 0 0 1 10 units box

I get the following:

which is easier to see if I replicate it:

From this, I understand that the rotate command in LAMMPS rotates the atoms in the simulation box.
How to make a rotation that as if an infinite plane is rotated, and only a finite simulation box is cut out of this plane? Is it possible to make such rotation after which the boundaries are still periodic?

if you rotate by 10 degree your periodic length along xyz will also change. It means you have to adjust simulation cell shape as well. Quick help for workaround https://atomsk.univ-lille.fr/tutorial_orient.php

@Pranavkumar Thanks, I read the text you suggested, and then did it with atomsk hBN.lmp -rotate Z 10 -orthogonal-cell hBN_10deg.lmp which solved the problem. This basically answers my question
